# Boost asio: unable to acknowledge a file transfer

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, asio

I am using boost asio to perform file transfers over TCP. The file transfer works, however when I decide to implement a simple acknowledge message from server to client by chaining `async_write` (on server) and `async_read_until` (on client), I observe a weird behaviour: the file is no longer received properly on the server side. A few hundred bytes before the end of the transfer the server just doesn't receive any more bytes and therefore never calls the `async_write` responsible for acknowledging the file transfer.

This seems to happen when I call `async_read_until` in my client after I am done writing the file. For some reason it affects the current file transfer.

Client implementation:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include "AsyncTCPClient.h"


AsyncTCPClient::AsyncTCPClient(boost::asio::io_service& iIoService, const std::string& iServerIP, const std::string& iPath)
    : mResolver(iIoService), mSocket(iIoService)
{
    size_t wPos = iServerIP.find(':');
    if(wPos==std::string::npos)
    {
        return;
    }
    std::string wPortStr = iServerIP.substr(wPos + 1);
    std::string wServerIP = iServerIP.substr(0, wPos);

    mSourceFile.open(iPath, std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::ate);
    if(!mSourceFile)
    {
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Failed to open file: " << iPath;
        return;
    }
    size_t wFileSize = mSourceFile.tellg();
    mSourceFile.seekg(0);
    std::ostream wRequestStream(&mRequest);
    wRequestStream << iPath << "\n" << wFileSize << "\n\n";

    LOG(LOGINFO) << "File to transfer: " << iPath;
    LOG(LOGINFO) << "Filesize: " << wFileSize << " bytes";

    tcp::resolver::query wQuery(wServerIP, wPortStr);
    mResolver.async_resolve(wQuery, boost::bind(&AsyncTCPClient::HandleResolve, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));

}

AsyncTCPClient::~AsyncTCPClient()
{
}

void AsyncTCPClient::HandleResolve(const boost::system::error_code & iErr, tcp::resolver::iterator iEndpointIterator)
{
    if(!iErr)
    {
        tcp::endpoint wEndpoint = *iEndpointIterator;
        mSocket.async_connect(wEndpoint, boost::bind(&AsyncTCPClient::HandleConnect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, ++iEndpointIterator));
    }
    else
    {
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Error: " << iErr.message();
    }
}

void AsyncTCPClient::HandleConnect(const boost::system::error_code &iErr, tcp::resolver::iterator iEndpointIterator)
{
    if(!iErr)
    {
        boost::asio::async_write(mSocket, mRequest, boost::bind(&AsyncTCPClient::HandleWriteFile, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else if(iEndpointIterator != tcp::resolver::iterator())
    {
        mSocket.close();
        tcp::endpoint wEndpoint = *iEndpointIterator;
        mSocket.async_connect(wEndpoint, boost::bind(&AsyncTCPClient::HandleConnect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, ++iEndpointIterator));
    }
    else
    {
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Error: " << iErr.message();
    }
}

void AsyncTCPClient::HandleWriteFile(const boost::system::error_code& iErr)
{
    if(!iErr)
    {
        if(mSourceFile)
        {
            mSourceFile.read(mBuffer.c_array(), (std::streamsize)mBuffer.size());

            // EOF reached
            if(mSourceFile.gcount() <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            //LOG(LOGTRACE) << "Send " << mSourceFile.gcount() << "bytes, total: " << mSourceFile.tellg() << " bytes.\n";
            boost::asio::async_write(mSocket, boost::asio::buffer(mBuffer.c_array(), mSourceFile.gcount()), boost::bind(&AsyncTCPClient::HandleWriteFile, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
            LOG(LOGINFO) << "File transfer done";
            /// async_read responsible for receiving a simple "ack[;]" once server is done receiving
            /// when I don't do this and simply return the server receives the file properly and sends the ack
            /// when I do this the server stops never receives the full file and simply waits for all the bytes to arrive which doesn't happen
            boost::asio::async_read_until(mSocket, mRecBuf, "[;]", boost::bind(&AsyncTCPClient::HandleReceiveAcknowledge, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Error value: " << iErr.value();
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Error message: " << iErr.message();
        throw std::exception();
    }
}
void AsyncTCPClient::HandleReceiveAcknowledge(const boost::system::error_code& iErr)
{
    if(!iErr)
    {
        std::string wRecData((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&mRecBuf)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        LOG(LOGDEBUG1) << "Acknowledged this data: " << wRecData;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // in case of error free resources and bail
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Error value: " << iErr.value();
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Error message: " << iErr.message();
        throw std::exception();
    }
}
```

Server implementation:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include "AsyncTCPClient.h"
#include "AsyncTCPServer.h"
#include "Debug.h"


AsyncTCPServer::AsyncTCPServer(unsigned short iPort, const std::string iFilePath)
    :mAcceptor(mIoService, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), iPort), true)
{
    mAsyncTCPConnectionPtr wNewConnection(new AsyncTCPConnection(mIoService, iFilePath));
    mAcceptor.async_accept(wNewConnection->Socket(), boost::bind(&AsyncTCPServer::HandleAccept, this, wNewConnection, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    mIoService.run();
}

AsyncTCPServer::~AsyncTCPServer()
{
    mIoService.stop();
}

void AsyncTCPServer::HandleAccept(mAsyncTCPConnectionPtr iCurConnection, const boost::system::error_code& iErr)
{
    if (!iErr)
    {
        iCurConnection->Start();
    }
    else
    {
        BIOLOG(BioSans::LOGERROR) << " " << iErr << ", " << iErr.message();
    }
}
```

Connection implementation:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Debug.h"
#include "AsyncTCPConnection.h"

AsyncTCPConnection::AsyncTCPConnection(boost::asio::io_service& iIoService, const std::string iFilePath)
    : mSocket(iIoService), mFileSize(0), mFilePath(iFilePath)
{
}

AsyncTCPConnection::~AsyncTCPConnection()
{
}

void AsyncTCPConnection::Start()
{
    LOG(LOGINFO) << "Start";
    async_read_until(mSocket, mRequestBuffer, "\n\n", boost::bind(&AsyncTCPConnection::HandleReadRequest, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void AsyncTCPConnection::HandleReadRequest(const boost::system::error_code& iErr, std::size_t iBytesTransferred)
{
    if(iErr)
    {
        return HandleError(__FUNCTION__, iErr);
    }
    LOG(LOGTRACE) << "(" << iBytesTransferred << ")" << ", in_avail = " << mRequestBuffer.in_avail() << ", size = " << mRequestBuffer.size() << ", max_size = " << mRequestBuffer.max_size();

    std::istream wRequestStream(&mRequestBuffer);
    std::string wFilePath;
    wRequestStream >> wFilePath;
    wRequestStream >> mFileSize;
    wRequestStream.read(mBuffer.c_array(), 2);

    mOutputFile.open(mFilePath, std::ios_base::binary);

    if(!mOutputFile)
    {
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Failed to open: " << wFilePath;
        return;
    }
    do
    {
        wRequestStream.read(mBuffer.c_array(), (std::streamsize)mBuffer.size());
        LOG(LOGTRACE) << "Write " << wRequestStream.gcount() << " bytes";
        mOutputFile.write(mBuffer.c_array(), wRequestStream.gcount());
    }
    while(wRequestStream.gcount() > 0);
    async_read(mSocket, boost::asio::buffer(mBuffer.c_array(), mBuffer.size()),boost::bind(&AsyncTCPConnection::HandleReadFileContent, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void AsyncTCPConnection::HandleReadFileContent(const boost::system::error_code& iErr, std::size_t iBytesTransferred)
{
    if(iBytesTransferred>0)
    {
        mOutputFile.write(mBuffer.c_array(), (std::streamsize)iBytesTransferred);
        LOG(LOGTRACE) << "Received " << mOutputFile.tellp() << " bytes";
        if (mOutputFile.tellp()>=(std::streamsize)mFileSize)
        {
            /// file is received, send a simple ack message
            /// this code is never reach when I launch the last async_read_until on the client side
            char *wAckMsg = "ack[;]";
            boost::asio::async_write(mSocket, boost::asio::buffer(wAckMsg, strlen(wAckMsg)), boost::bind(&AsyncTCPConnection::HandleAcknowledge, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
    }
    if(iErr)
    {
        return HandleError(__FUNCTION__, iErr);
    }
    async_read(mSocket, boost::asio::buffer(mBuffer.c_array(), mBuffer.size()), boost::bind(&AsyncTCPConnection::HandleReadFileContent, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void AsyncTCPConnection::HandleAcknowledge(const boost::system::error_code& iErr)
{
    if(!iErr)
    {
        LOG(LOGDEBUG1) << "Message acknowledged";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // in case of error free resources and bail
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Error value: " << iErr.value();
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Error message: " << iErr.message();
        throw std::exception();
    }
}

void AsyncTCPConnection::HandleError(const std::string& function_name, const boost::system::error_code& err)
{
    LOG(LOGERROR) << " in " << function_name <<" due to " << err <<" " << err.message();
}
```

Code to send file:

```
        boost::asio::io_service wIoService;
        AsyncTCPClient client(wIoService, iServerIP, iFilePath);
        wIoService.run();
```

I looked for an answer forever I simply cannot understand what/why is happening. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the server (receiving) side, you repeat

```
async_read(mSocket, boost::asio::buffer(mBuffer.c_array(), mBuffer.size()),
           boost::bind(&AsyncTCPConnection::HandleReadFileContent, shared_from_this(),
                       boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

until you're done. This always seemed to work well, because the last read would return with eof:

> This function is used to asynchronously read a certain number of bytes of data from a stream. The function call always returns immediately. The asynchronous operation will continue until one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The supplied buffer is full (that is, it has reached maximum size).
> - An error occurred.

But now, since the client does **not** close the socket (because it's waiting for ACK), you keep trying to read until you fill the *whole* buffer. If your file happened to be of the right size you *might* achieve it by accident.

---

#### Other problems:

```
char *wAckMsg = "ack[;]";
boost::asio::async_write(
    mSocket, boost::asio::buffer(wAckMsg, strlen(wAckMsg)),
    boost::bind(&AsyncTCPConnection::HandleAcknowledge, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

In these 5 lines there are as many errors:

- string literals can **not** be treated as `char*`, instead MUST be treated as `char const (&)[]`
- the buffer points to that local variable. You're, again, probably lucky because string literals usually reside in a static data segment, and the local was merely a pointer to it, but this is not something you should rely on. The local variable doesn't exist during the asynchronous operation, which might lead to [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) depending on the compiler used
- you bind the completion handler to `this` instead of `shared_from_this`. This means that the last reference to the `mAsyncTCPConnectionPtr` would be released, and `~AsyncTCPConnectionPtr` runs. This will destroy the socket, which may or may not happen before completion of sending the Ack. In a multi-threaded server this could easily lead to [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to the data race.
- after posting the async_write, you do not exit the function. This means that subsequent code is still executed, including the next `async_read(mSocket, boost::asio::buffer(mBuffer.c_array(), mBuffer.size()), ...`.

I'd suggest the following as a minimum fix:

```
static char const *s_wAckMsg = "ack[;]";
boost::asio::async_write(
    mSocket, boost::asio::buffer(s_wAckMsg, strlen(s_wAckMsg)),
    boost::bind(&AsyncTCPConnection::HandleAcknowledge, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error));
return;
```

---

#### Minor other issues

Request parsing is not robust (errors aren't handled, neither is the format checked. At the end you just consume 2 characters blindly, which are just *assumed* to be `'\n\n'`, but you never know).

You report the wrong filename if opening the output file fails.

You can use `boost::asio::async_connect` instead of the awkward handler chain.

There's no need to build a string using `istreambuf_iterator<char>` if all you want to do is print it.

### Let's attempt to fix it

I wrote a metric ton of code to compile the code, and attempted to fix the bug by reducing the read size.

The `async_read` call is duplicated, so let's remove the duplication:

```
void AsyncTCPConnection::DoReceiveFileContent() {
    size_t expect = (mFileSize <= mOutputFile.tellp())? 0 : mFileSize - mOutputFile.tellp();
    LOG(LOGDEBUG1) << "expectedContent: " << expect;
    expect = std::min(mBuffer.size(), expect);

    async_read(mSocket, boost::asio::buffer(mBuffer.c_array(), expect),
               boost::bind(&AsyncTCPConnection::HandleReadFileContent, shared_from_this(),
                           boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

Now we just call `DoReceiveFileContent()` whenever we want to schedule more read operations.

## DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfefbf4212590058)</kbd>**

```
//#include "AsyncTCPConnection.h"
//#include "Debug.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct Buffer {
    size_t size() const { return sizeof(m_array); }
    char const *c_array() const { return m_array; }
    char *c_array() { return m_array; }

  private:
    char m_array[1024]{ 0 };
};

struct LogTx {
    LogTx(std::string const &name) { std::cout << name << "\t"; }
    LogTx(LogTx &&other) : armed(other.armed) { other.armed = false; }
    ~LogTx() { if (armed) std::cout << std::endl; }

    template <typename... T> friend LogTx operator<<(LogTx tx, T &&... args) {
        std::cout << (args << ...);
        return tx;
    }
  private:
    bool armed = true;
};

#define LOG(x) LogTx("LOG:" #x)
#define BIOLOG(x) LogTx("BIOLOG:" #x)
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

struct AsyncTCPConnection : boost::enable_shared_from_this<AsyncTCPConnection> {
    AsyncTCPConnection(boost::asio::io_service &iIoService, const std::string iFilePath);
    ~AsyncTCPConnection();
    void Start();
    void HandleReadRequest(const boost::system::error_code &iErr, std::size_t iBytesTransferred);
    void HandleReadFileContent(const boost::system::error_code &iErr, std::size_t iBytesTransferred);
    void DoReceiveFileContent();
    void HandleAcknowledge(const boost::system::error_code &iErr);
    void HandleError(const std::string &function_name, const boost::system::error_code &err);

    tcp::socket &Socket() { return mSocket; }

  private:
    boost::asio::streambuf mRequestBuffer;
    Buffer mBuffer;
    tcp::socket mSocket;
    std::streamsize mFileSize;
    std::string mOutputFilePath;
    std::ofstream mOutputFile;
};

AsyncTCPConnection::AsyncTCPConnection(boost::asio::io_service &iIoService, const std::string iFilePath)
        : mSocket(iIoService), mFileSize(0), mOutputFilePath(iFilePath) {}

AsyncTCPConnection::~AsyncTCPConnection() {}

void AsyncTCPConnection::Start() {
    LOG(LOGINFO) << "Start";
    async_read_until(mSocket, mRequestBuffer, "\n\n",
                     boost::bind(&AsyncTCPConnection::HandleReadRequest, shared_from_this(),
                                 boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void AsyncTCPConnection::HandleReadRequest(const boost::system::error_code &iErr, std::size_t iBytesTransferred) {
    if (iErr) {
        return HandleError(__FUNCTION__, iErr);
    }
    LOG(LOGTRACE) << "(" << iBytesTransferred << ")"
                  << ", in_avail = " << mRequestBuffer.in_avail() << ", size = " << mRequestBuffer.size();

    std::istream wRequestStream(&mRequestBuffer);
    std::string wFilePath;
    wRequestStream >> wFilePath;
    LOG(LOGTRACE) << "Original filename " << wFilePath;
    wRequestStream >> mFileSize;
    LOG(LOGTRACE) << "Original filesize " << mFileSize;
    wRequestStream.read(mBuffer.c_array(), 2);

    mOutputFile.open(mOutputFilePath, std::ios_base::binary);

    if (!wRequestStream) {
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Request could not be parsed";
        return;
    }
    if (!mOutputFile) {
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Failed to open: " << mOutputFilePath;
        return;
    }
    do {
        wRequestStream.read(mBuffer.c_array(), (std::streamsize)mBuffer.size());
        LOG(LOGTRACE) << "Write " << wRequestStream.gcount() << " bytes";
        mOutputFile.write(mBuffer.c_array(), wRequestStream.gcount());
    } while (wRequestStream.gcount() > 0);

    DoReceiveFileContent();
}

void AsyncTCPConnection::DoReceiveFileContent() {
    size_t expect = (mFileSize <= mOutputFile.tellp())? 0 : mFileSize - mOutputFile.tellp();
    LOG(LOGDEBUG1) << "expectedContent: " << expect;
    expect = std::min(mBuffer.size(), expect);

    async_read(mSocket, boost::asio::buffer(mBuffer.c_array(), expect),
               boost::bind(&AsyncTCPConnection::HandleReadFileContent, shared_from_this(),
                           boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void AsyncTCPConnection::HandleReadFileContent(const boost::system::error_code &iErr, std::size_t iBytesTransferred) {
    if (iBytesTransferred > 0) {
        mOutputFile.write(mBuffer.c_array(), (std::streamsize)iBytesTransferred);
        LOG(LOGTRACE) << "Received " << mOutputFile.tellp() << " bytes (+" << iBytesTransferred << ")";
        if (mOutputFile.tellp() >= (std::streamsize)mFileSize) {
            LOG(LOGTRACE) << "Receive complete at " << mFileSize << " bytes";
            /// file is received, send a simple ack message
            /// this code is never reach when I launch the last async_read_until on the client side
            static char const *s_wAckMsg = "ack[;]";
            boost::asio::async_write(
                mSocket, boost::asio::buffer(s_wAckMsg, strlen(s_wAckMsg)),
                boost::bind(&AsyncTCPConnection::HandleAcknowledge, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error));
            return;
        }
    }
    if (iErr) {
        return HandleError(__FUNCTION__, iErr);
    }
    DoReceiveFileContent();
}

void AsyncTCPConnection::HandleAcknowledge(const boost::system::error_code &iErr) {
    if (!iErr) {
        LOG(LOGDEBUG1) << "Message ACK sent";
        return;
    } else {
        // in case of error free resources and bail
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Error value: " << iErr.value();
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Error message: " << iErr.message();
        throw std::exception();
    }
}

void AsyncTCPConnection::HandleError(const std::string &function_name, const boost::system::error_code &err) {
    LOG(LOGERROR) << " in " << function_name << " due to " << err << " " << err.message();
}

#include <boost/thread.hpp>
//#include "AsyncTCPClient.h"

struct AsyncTCPClient {
    AsyncTCPClient(boost::asio::io_service &iIoService, const std::string &iServerIP, const std::string &iPath);
    ~AsyncTCPClient();

    std::ifstream mSourceFile;
    boost::asio::streambuf mRequest, mAckBuf;
    tcp::resolver mResolver;
    tcp::socket mSocket;

    void HandleResolve(const boost::system::error_code &iErr, tcp::resolver::iterator iEndpointIterator);
    void HandleConnect(const boost::system::error_code &iErr, tcp::resolver::iterator iEndpointIterator);
    void HandleWriteFile(const boost::system::error_code &iErr);
    void HandleReceiveAcknowledge(const boost::system::error_code &iErr);

    Buffer mBuffer;
};

AsyncTCPClient::AsyncTCPClient(boost::asio::io_service &iIoService, const std::string &iServerIP,
                               const std::string &iPath)
        : mResolver(iIoService), mSocket(iIoService) {
    size_t wPos = iServerIP.find(':');
    if (wPos == std::string::npos) {
        return;
    }
    std::string wPortStr = iServerIP.substr(wPos + 1);
    std::string wServerIP = iServerIP.substr(0, wPos);

    mSourceFile.open(iPath, std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::ate);
    if (!mSourceFile) {
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Failed to open file: " << iPath;
        return;
    }
    size_t wFileSize = mSourceFile.tellg();
    mSourceFile.seekg(0);
    std::ostream wRequestStream(&mRequest);
    wRequestStream << iPath << "\n" << wFileSize << "\n\n";

    LOG(LOGINFO) << "File to transfer: " << iPath;
    LOG(LOGINFO) << "Filesize: " << wFileSize << " bytes";

    tcp::resolver::query wQuery(wServerIP, wPortStr);
    mResolver.async_resolve(wQuery, boost::bind(&AsyncTCPClient::HandleResolve, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));
}

AsyncTCPClient::~AsyncTCPClient() {}

void AsyncTCPClient::HandleResolve(const boost::system::error_code &iErr, tcp::resolver::iterator iEndpointIterator) {
    if (!iErr) {
        tcp::endpoint wEndpoint = *iEndpointIterator;
        mSocket.async_connect(wEndpoint, boost::bind(&AsyncTCPClient::HandleConnect, this,
                                                     boost::asio::placeholders::error, ++iEndpointIterator));
    } else {
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Error: " << iErr.message();
    }
}

void AsyncTCPClient::HandleConnect(const boost::system::error_code &iErr, tcp::resolver::iterator iEndpointIterator) {
    if (!iErr) {
        boost::asio::async_write(mSocket, mRequest,
                                 boost::bind(&AsyncTCPClient::HandleWriteFile, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    } else if (iEndpointIterator != tcp::resolver::iterator()) {
        mSocket.close();
        tcp::endpoint wEndpoint = *iEndpointIterator;
        mSocket.async_connect(wEndpoint, boost::bind(&AsyncTCPClient::HandleConnect, this,
                                                     boost::asio::placeholders::error, ++iEndpointIterator));
    } else {
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Error: " << iErr.message();
    }
}

void AsyncTCPClient::HandleWriteFile(const boost::system::error_code &iErr) {
    if (!iErr) {
        if (mSourceFile) {
            mSourceFile.read(mBuffer.c_array(), (std::streamsize)mBuffer.size());

            // EOF reached
            if (mSourceFile.gcount() <= 0) {
                LOG(LOGINFO) << "EOF reached";
                return;
            }

            // LOG(LOGTRACE) << "Send " << mSourceFile.gcount() << "bytes, total: " << mSourceFile.tellg() << "
            // bytes.\n";
            boost::asio::async_write(
                mSocket, boost::asio::buffer(mBuffer.c_array(), mSourceFile.gcount()),
                boost::bind(&AsyncTCPClient::HandleWriteFile, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        } else {
            LOG(LOGINFO) << "File transmission done";
            /// async_read responsible for receiving a simple "ack[;]" once server is done receiving
            /// when I don't do this and simply return the server receives the file properly and sends the ack
            /// when I do this the server stops never receives the full file and simply waits for all the bytes to
            /// arrive which doesn't happen
            boost::asio::async_read_until(
                mSocket, mAckBuf, "[;]",
                boost::bind(&AsyncTCPClient::HandleReceiveAcknowledge, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
    } else {
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Error value: " << iErr.value();
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Error message: " << iErr.message();
        throw std::exception();
    }
}

void AsyncTCPClient::HandleReceiveAcknowledge(const boost::system::error_code &iErr) {
    if (!iErr) {
        LOG(LOGDEBUG1) << "Acknowledged this data: " << &mAckBuf;
        return;
    } else {
        // in case of error free resources and bail
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Error value: " << iErr.value();
        LOG(LOGERROR) << "Error message: " << iErr.message();
        throw std::exception();
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
//#include "AsyncTCPClient.h"
//#include "AsyncTCPServer.h"
//#include "Debug.h"

struct AsyncTCPServer {
    using mAsyncTCPConnectionPtr = boost::shared_ptr<AsyncTCPConnection>;

    AsyncTCPServer(unsigned short iPort, const std::string iFilePath);
    ~AsyncTCPServer();
    void HandleAccept(mAsyncTCPConnectionPtr iCurConnection, const boost::system::error_code &iErr);

    boost::asio::io_service mIoService;
    tcp::acceptor mAcceptor;
};

AsyncTCPServer::AsyncTCPServer(unsigned short iPort, const std::string iFilePath)
        : mAcceptor(mIoService, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), iPort), true) {
    mAsyncTCPConnectionPtr wNewConnection(new AsyncTCPConnection(mIoService, iFilePath));
    mAcceptor.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
    mAcceptor.async_accept(wNewConnection->Socket(), boost::bind(&AsyncTCPServer::HandleAccept, this, wNewConnection,
                                                                 boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    mIoService.run();
}

AsyncTCPServer::~AsyncTCPServer() { mIoService.stop(); }

void AsyncTCPServer::HandleAccept(mAsyncTCPConnectionPtr iCurConnection, const boost::system::error_code &iErr) {
    if (!iErr) {
        iCurConnection->Start();
    } else {
        BIOLOG(BioSans::LOGERROR) << " " << iErr << ", " << iErr.message();
    }
}

int main() {
    boost::thread th([] {
        boost::asio::io_service wIoService;
        AsyncTCPClient client(wIoService, "127.0.0.1:6767", 
                //"/etc/dictionaries-common/words"
                "main.cpp"
            );
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
        wIoService.run();
    });

    AsyncTCPServer server(6767, "outputfile.txt");
}
```

Prints

```
LOG:LOGINFO File to transfer: main.cpp
LOG:LOGINFO Filesize: 12793 bytes
LOG:LOGINFO Start
LOG:LOGTRACE    (16), in_avail = 512, size = 512
LOG:LOGTRACE    Original filename main.cpp
LOG:LOGTRACE    Original filesize 12793
LOG:LOGTRACE    Write 496 bytes
LOG:LOGTRACE    Write 0 bytes
LOG:LOGDEBUG1   expectedContent: 12297
LOG:LOGINFO File transmission done
LOG:LOGTRACE    Received 1520 bytes (+1024)
LOG:LOGDEBUG1   expectedContent: 11273
LOG:LOGTRACE    Received 2544 bytes (+1024)
LOG:LOGDEBUG1   expectedContent: 10249
LOG:LOGTRACE    Received 3568 bytes (+1024)
LOG:LOGDEBUG1   expectedContent: 9225
LOG:LOGTRACE    Received 4592 bytes (+1024)
LOG:LOGDEBUG1   expectedContent: 8201
LOG:LOGTRACE    Received 5616 bytes (+1024)
LOG:LOGDEBUG1   expectedContent: 7177
LOG:LOGTRACE    Received 6640 bytes (+1024)
LOG:LOGDEBUG1   expectedContent: 6153
LOG:LOGTRACE    Received 7664 bytes (+1024)
LOG:LOGDEBUG1   expectedContent: 5129
LOG:LOGTRACE    Received 8688 bytes (+1024)
LOG:LOGDEBUG1   expectedContent: 4105
LOG:LOGTRACE    Received 9712 bytes (+1024)
LOG:LOGDEBUG1   expectedContent: 3081
LOG:LOGTRACE    Received 10736 bytes (+1024)
LOG:LOGDEBUG1   expectedContent: 2057
LOG:LOGTRACE    Received 11760 bytes (+1024)
LOG:LOGDEBUG1   expectedContent: 1033
LOG:LOGTRACE    Received 12784 bytes (+1024)
LOG:LOGDEBUG1   expectedContent: 9
LOG:LOGTRACE    Received 12793 bytes (+9)
LOG:LOGTRACE    Receive complete at 12793 bytes
LOG:LOGDEBUG1   Message ACK sent
LOG:LOGDEBUG1   Acknowledged this data: ack[;]
```

And indeed the file is identical:

```
d61f0515bc4ba003497d67e265b5e0bc  main.cpp
d61f0515bc4ba003497d67e265b5e0bc  outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the incredible answer. By the time you answered I realized that the main problem was the size of the read and implemented a fix similar to yours, but you also pointed out many other issues and provided very valuable feedback.

Comment: @ajora It's nice to update your question if you find additional information. Also see here a version [using standard library and not using bind](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31927e8bfe456512). Even more interesting, [a version using coroutines](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7f24c4055284feb)